# Send parameter value via React routing

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use Link from react-router-dom to send a parameter to another page.

I have this path:

```
<Route path={"/IDSM/IDSMAdmin/EditUser/:username"} component={EditUser}/>
```

Here's the link that gets there:

```
<Link to={"/IDSM/IDSMAdmin/EditUser/${item}"}>{item}</Link>
```

But that doesn't send the value of {item} to the other page. Instead it just sends the literal value "${item}".

```
{ username: "${{item}}" }
```

How can I send the contents of {item} itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use back-tick character instead of double quotes to send the params

```
<Link to={`/IDSM/IDSMAdmin/EditUser/${item}`}>text here</Link>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass param to another component:

```
<Route path={"/IDSM/IDSMAdmin/EditUser/:username"} component={EditUser}/>

export default class EditUser extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.match.params.username}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```